# rename the txt file extension using perl

Tags: perl

I am doing the below steps:

Read all the text files in a directory and store it in an array named @files
Run a foreach loop on each text file. Extract the file name(stripping of .txt) using split operation and creating a folder of that particular filename. Rename that file to Test.txt (so as to work as input fo another perl executable) Executing test.pl for each file by adding the line require "test.pl";
It works fine for only one file, but not any more. Here is my code:

```
opendir DIR, ".";
my @files = grep {/\.txt/} readdir DIR;

foreach my $files (@files) {

    @fn = split '\.', $files;
    mkdir "$fn[0]" 
        or die "Unable to create $fn[0] directory <$!>\n";

    rename "$files", "Test.txt";
    require "test3.pl";

    rename "Test.txt", "$files";
    system "move $files $fn[0]";
}
```

Comment: add checks for rename => `rename .. or die "rename failed"`. Drop system call for `move` and use `File::Copy` http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html

Answer (score 2):

you don't `require` the file to be loaded once, but [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html)ne every time.

So, replace

require "test3.pl";

with

do "test3.pl";

Answer (score 1):

Can you glob for files in that directory..

Replace,

```
opendir DIR, ".";
my @files = grep {/\.txt/} readdir DIR;
```

with,

```
my @files = <*.txt>;
```